# How to inherit model & remove unwanted fields OpenERP.?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

in my model class i inherit hr.employee model.but i not need some fields from that model.how to remove those fields.?

```
class madulsima_plucker(osv.osv):
    _name = "madulsima.plucker"
    _description = "This table is for keeping personal data of madulsima pluckers"
    _inherit = "hr.employee"
    _columns = {
        'reg_no': fields.char('Registration Number', size=256, required=True),
        'worker_name': fields.char('Worker Name', size=256, required=True)
    }

madulsima_plucker()
```

and i also try with view.xml for remove those fields as per developer book.its not worked.where is my issue .?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <!-- 1st part of the sim_view start -->
        <record model="ir.ui.view" id="madulsima_plucker_form">
            <field name="name">madulsima.plucker.form</field>
            <field name="model">madulsima.plucker</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="hr.view_employee_form" />
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <notebook position="inside">
                    <page string="Madulsima Plucker Fields">
                        <field name="reg_no" />
                        <field name="worker_name" />
                        <field name="ssnid" position="replace" />
                        <field name="sinid" position="replace" />
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </field>
        </record>

        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="action_plucker_registration">
            <field name="name">Plucker Registration</field>
            <field name="res_model">madulsima.plucker</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        </record>


        <menuitem id="menu_madulsima_plucker" name="Madulsima/Checkroll" />

        <menuitem id="menu_madulsima_plucker_registration" name="Plucker Registration"
            parent="menu_madulsima_plucker" action="action_plucker_registration" />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

Comment: Can you give more infomration which things you want to remove?

Comment: if you want to remove sinid and ssnid fields then it works perfactly, it will remove fields from views

Comment: yes both fields which i need to remove.but those are still shows in my view.

Comment: Have you updated your database after wrote this code using -u module_name -d database name

Comment: need to restart server with these params.?
then
openerp-server -u madulsima_plucker -d openerp_db   ?

Comment: yes, then changes apply

Answer (score 0):

Your `arch` is wrong.
Use this:

```
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
           <field name="ssnid" position="replace" />
           <field name="sinid" position="replace" />
        </field>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<field name="ssnid" position="attributes" >
    <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
</field>
```

in your view.xml just use code above to hide any field you want to hide,, change it to `<field name="ssnid"`

Comment: so u have to know the field name, for to know the field name,, 

go to about odoo -> active developer mode

then hover the name.. and you will gate the information of the name field

Answer (score 0):

use attribute invisible ... i think it's the best solution don't replace it maybe other fields depends on it

```
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <xpath expr="//field[@name='ssnid']" position="attributes">
      <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
    </xpath>
</field>
```